# Why would adding a Mesh Collider make Inverse Kinematic legs mess up their movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, mesh, collider

Without mesh collider: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElIFJ.jpg

With mesh collider: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tjtt.jpg (See how legs now walk unpredictably)

Can someone please explain what is the cause of this? Is it colliding with itself somehow? I don't know where to begin trying to fix this.

In case anyone is interested, the gecko setup is from a very cool procedural animation tutorial here: https://www.weaverdev.io/blog/bonehead-procedural-animation

Thank you for any help.

edit: Solved .. ended up being an unpredictable issue from my end (indeed it involved layers). Added my own answer to this which I will accept when it lets me. Thank you so much though for the assistance.

Comment: It looks pretty nice indeed ;) In the second it seems to collide with itself instead of the floor, yes. Maybe [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and [Layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) would solve this

Comment: Hm, I guess it's not working. I created a new layer called 'Gecko' and set the Gecko gameobject (and all of its children) to that layer. I then went into Project Settings and into Layer Collision Matrix and unchecked the "Gecko/Gecko" box. But the problem is still persisting, unfortunately. Any other ideas would be appreciated. Also when I tested `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collide)     {         Debug.Log("I hit the GameObject : " + collide.gameObject.name);     }` it didn't output colliding with itself in the console. Not sure if that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feet movement was being controlled by Raycasting to Ground layer, but the ground layer was incorrectly set up on my end. This was therefore solved by correcting that issue. D'oh. Now collisions and movement work perfectly. Thank you all.